# Model Deforms When I move A Bone

Tags: animation, bones

When I parented my rig to my model with automatic weights. The model deforms when I try to pose it. The arm bone attaches to the leg and pulls with it.

**EXAMPLE:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4I49.png

(please note: Im rather new to rigging in BLENDER)

Answer (score 1):

The automatic weights aren't perfect, you can manually decide what part of the mesh gets to be controlled by what bone.

It's called weight painting.

Here is a [tutorial for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBS1qy4jzTg).